# Windows logs off immediately after logging in

Tags: windows-7, login, logout

My university has an application that students must run it to do tests (midterm, final,...). It's really annoying to all students. It will close all files it can close on the computer (system files too). So, users must turn account control to default level so this app cannot auto close it.

I don't know this before. My account control is on the lowest level. So, when I run this app, it will automatically restart (because some system file has been closed). After two times, I login and get this behavior: No matter how I login, Windows says "Welcome", and logs off permantly after.

When I create another account and set account control to default level, I can run this app and can logon.

But I still want to use the old account (many settings I have set before).

Comment: Is this application installed on your personal computer or on a university computer? If it is not your own computer, this is an issue you will have to resolve with your school's IT department.

Comment: @iglvzx of course is my personal computer. it really annoy me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just take the time to setup the new account and ONLY use that account for your school work, while doing everything else on your usual account?  This could prevent (or at least minimize) anything changing to make your school account to not work.

Yes, maybe it's an annoyance to do the setup work... but consider the future... it's only annoying ONCE, rather than every time you try to do your school work.

Comment: ah. yes, that how i'm doing :D I have created a new account to do a test. but before that, I don't know that :( very very stupid software.